# Undo Git --amend -> Delete commit

Tags: git

I have been searching for a solution to this mistake I did. Can't find it anywhere.

I was working on a larger change, and I did a commit --ammend to add this as a patch to my earlier smaller change. However, for some reason, I deleted the commit --ammend message in editor (which unfortunately deleted my commit as a whole). So I am now left without my changes, anywhere. Is there any way I can get my changes/files back?

ps I have learned my lesson not to keep the changes without committing them for very long. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If `git commit` fails it should not delete you changes. What does `git diff --cached` say?

Comment: it does not show me anything when I do git diff. When I did a git commit --ammend, it did say that "if you delete the comm it message, it will delete the commit as a whole". I think that's what happened. Please help :(

Comment: I have just tested this and aborting the amended commit leaves me on the pre-amended commit with my changes staged. What version of Git are you using? What does `git status` say?

Comment: git status does not show anything. I 'did' do a pull recently, could that have deleted my changes? Is there a way to undo?

Comment: `git pull` should also not delete your changes. Did you do `git pull` after aborting your amend? What exactly have you done since the failed amend command?

Comment: It says “an empty message aborts the commit”, that means that the commit won't be ammended but it won't be removed of course. Please, try to recall what exactly you did, as your problem is something different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, not keeping uncommitted changes is indeed a valuable lesson. Before doing something important always look at your uncommitted changes and decide if you want to commit or discard them. (A well set up prompt will help you recognize if you workspace is dirty.)

Pretty much everything you ever committed is save and can be restored at any time. The tricky part is to identify the commit you want.

There are usually two ways to do so: `git log` and `git reflog`.

With `git log` you can list the official history of a branch. As long as you only commit your work once in a while that should be enough. If you however change your history by amending or rebasing you obviously will no longer able to see the abandoned version in the normal `git log`.

That is where `git reflog` comes in handy. This will record pretty much all actions you did together with the commit id which was the result of your action. Just type `git reflog` and you get a list of actions you should recognize. Time goes from bottom to top. Commit something and you get a new entry on top.

If you want to restore an old version just scan through the list for the wanted entry and use `git reset` to time-warp there. :)